# Drupal views - Show no exposed filter options when no results come from view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I have a problem. I have a view that is getting back no results like it should, for the context it is in. I have a list of resources (file nodes) that are associated to an organic group. For this view I use exposed filters that should only show filter options that apply to the result set.

For example, if I have only one "folder" associated with this group then I should only see one folder in the exposed filter for folders. If I have none then none should show up. The problem is that when we have none it is showing ALL the folders for the site. Same with the associated topics and other filter fields.

Currently we are using the views_hacks > views_filters_selective module to accomplish the initial filtering. But it doesn't seem to handle the case when the view has no results. And I am having trouble figuring out how (and where) to identify when it has no results so that I can just eliminate all the filter options.

Now to be a little extra honest about this, we actually copied some of the functions from the above mentioned module and improved it (for performance purposes) within a custom module we wrote. But like I said, I am having a tough time trying to identify when the view has no initial results at all.

Does anyone have any idea as to how to do this? We are running this in Drupal/Pressflow 6 with Views 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to set it to not empty for that field and it works fine.